# How to add ribbon tab with content created from class

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm up against a very simple problem I guess, however I find no way to solve it.

I basically want to create a ribbon tab with all it´s content from a class:

```
class RibbonTabHome
{
    public RibbonTab RibbonTab_Container;

    public RibbonTabHome()
    {
        RibbonTab_Container = new RibbonTab() { Header = "Wont appear!" };
    }
}
```

I then call the class and add the tab to the ribbon:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    RibbonTabHome asd = new RibbonTabHome();

    RibbonMain.Items.Add(asd.RibbonTab_Container);
}
```

For some reason only the tab container itself is added, the header text is missing!

However this statement does its work perfectly!

```
RibbonMain.Items.Add(new RibbonTab() { Header = "Appearing"});
```

What am I missing?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

It seems that you are missing a great deal. WPF is simply *not* written like that. In WPF, we manipulate *data elements*, not *UI elements*. We declare `DataTemplate`s that define how our data should be rendered in the UI, so to add a new `TabItem` in a `TabControl`, you add a new *data* item into a *data* collection that is data bound to the `ItemsSource` property of the `TabControl`.

So you *can* create a `RibbonTab` from classes, but those classes do *not* manually build the UI elements, instead they provide the *data* for the controls. For example, to add a `Button`, you'd need a class that had a couple of `string` properties to data bind to the `Button.Content` and `ToolTip` properties. It would also need an `ICommand` property to data bind to the actual `Command` property. To add a new `Button`, you just add another of these classes into the relevant collection.

As to what class goes in what collection, well that is far to long a story to cover here. Luckily, the topic of data binding `RibbonTab` controls has been widely discussed online, so you'll have plenty of good sources for that. Don't forget MSDN is a great resource... there are plenty of relevant links from the [Ribbon Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx) page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I have studied bindings and datatemplates now and starting to get the hang of it. Im still having one issue with the datatemplate. I would be very greateful if you checkout my new question at:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966941/whats-wrong-datatemplate-with-itemssource