# How to render a Ribbon from data objects using ItemsSource and DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Im trying to supply a data template to my ribbon.

The ribbon is declared as following, and has an ItemTemplate attached to it.

```
<r:Ribbon Name="RibbonMain"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeRibbonTabTemplate}">
</r:Ribbon>
```

The Datatemplate is the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RibbonContainer}" 
                  x:Key="HomeRibbonTabTemplate">
        <r:RibbonTab Header="{Binding Path=HeaderName}">
            <r:RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Path=GroupName}">
            </r:RibbonGroup>
        </r:RibbonTab>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I do then attach the ItemsSource:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var RibbonTabData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonContainer>();
        RibbonTabData.Add(new RibbonContainer("HeaderName", "GroupName"));
        RibbonMain.ItemsSource = RibbonTabData;
    }
```

Lastly the class: (Which just contains two string fields)

```
class RibbonContainer
{
    public string HeaderName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string GroupName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RibbonContainer(string _headername, string _groupname)
    {
        HeaderName = _headername;
        GroupName = _groupname;
    }
}
```

I get the unimpressive result of showing the fully qualified class name in the tab header and neither is the ribbongroup showing. (This is what the datatemplate should solve?)
What to do?

Best regards

Comment: Hmm as far I understand your issue you set a list of containers to be the ItemsSource of your Ribbon control. That will automatically result in Ribbon creating RibbonTabs for you. Futhermore you wish to template each RibbonTab with certain formatation. But the problem is that you define another RibbonTab which shall be placed inside the first automatically created RibbonTab. Therefore you app starts acting weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where to start, but perhaps with a short warning that, in trying to create a `RibbonControl` totally from data `Binding` and data items, you *really* are opening up a huge can of *whoop ass* on yourself. This is because the developers that designed the code for it used unconventional patterns for some of it and failed to adequately document how to do things with it. Some of the best sources will be found by searching on this website.

So anyway, if you're up for a painful, uphill struggle, read on. Your first mistake was trying to use a `DataTemplate` for the `RibbonTab` because it is extends [`System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and therefore requires a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your second mistake was declaring the `RibbonTab` inside the template, as @devhedgehog mentioned in a comment.

You third mistake was setting the `x:Key` value for your `DataTemplate` and applying it to the `Ribbon.ItemsTemplate` property... I know, I know... a sensible enough thing to do *if this wasn't a `RibbonControl`*. You'll have to ask those developers as to *why* that doesn't work, but you're better off just accepting that it doesn't and adapting your code. You just need to remove the `x:Key` value and the `Ribbon.ItemsTemplate` property and let the Framework apply the template *implicitly*.

Now if you ever want more than one `RibbonGroup`, then your fourth mistake was defining that in the template for the `RibbonTab`. If you're going to do this properly, then your data classes will need to match the various levels of UI elements in the `Ribbon`. By this, I mean that you need to create a `RibbonGroupData` class too. That class needs a collection of `RibbonButtonData` objects that supply the data to each `RibbonButton` in the UI. So you should end up with something like this:

```
public class RibbonTabData : BaseDataType
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<RibbonGroupData> ribbonGroupData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonGroupData>();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RibbonGroupData> RibbonGroupData
    {
        get { return ribbonGroupData; }
        set { ribbonGroupData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("RibbonGroupData"); }
    }
}

public class RibbonGroupData : BaseDataType
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<RibbonButtonData> ribbonButtonData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonButtonData>();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RibbonButtonData> RibbonButtonData
    {
        get { return ribbonButtonData; }
        set { ribbonButtonData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("RibbonButtonData"); }
    }
}

public class RibbonButtonData : BaseDataType
{
    private string name = string.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
}
```

The `BaseDataType` class just implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Of course, you'd need to add extra properties for `ICommand`s and image sources, etc. You might even need different `RibbonButtonData` classes with different properties for different types of `RibbonButton`s and then you'd need a common `RibbonButtonBaseData` class that they all extended, so your collection could contain all the different types together. So there's lots more for you to do, but given this example code, you could display it in the `Ribbon` like this:

```
<Ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:RibbonTabData}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonGroupData}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:RibbonButtonData}">
        <Ribbon:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Name}" 
            LargeImageSource="/WpfRibbonApplication1;component/Images/LargeIcon.png" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:RibbonGroupData}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonButtonData}">
        <Ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
<Ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonTabData}" />
```

Now in the view model that is set as the `DataContext` for the `Window`, I can add some dummy data to test that it all works:

```
RibbonTabData.Add(new RibbonTabData() { Name = "Tab 1", RibbonGroupData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonGroupData>() { new RibbonGroupData() { Name = "Group 1", RibbonButtonData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonButtonData>() { new RibbonButtonData() { Name = "Button 1" }, new RibbonButtonData() { Name = "Button 2" }, new RibbonButtonData() { Name = "Button 3" } } }, new RibbonGroupData() { Name = "Group 2", RibbonButtonData = new ObservableCollection<RibbonButtonData>() { new RibbonButtonData() { Name = "Button 1" }, new RibbonButtonData() { Name = "Button 2" } } } } });
RibbonTabData.Add(new RibbonTabData() { Name = "Tab 2" });
RibbonTabData.Add(new RibbonTabData() { Name = "Tab 3" });
```

And we get this:

[image]

However, even with this helpful start, you've still got a *lot* more work to do.

Comment: My biggest thanks! I have succesfully managed to add different controls dynamically. (See answer below)
I have to praise your proffesional knowledge and skill in WPF. Your a talent, it´s so easy to add events and everything now!

Answer (score 1):

By reading Sheridans answer I managed to create the following result:

[image]

(Different controls with the possibility to attach event handlers to wanted control).

How I did the event handling (example with ribbonbutton)

1. Attach a tag property to your ribbonbutton template (with databinding of course)
2. Attach an loaded event into your ribbonbutton template
3. Create a dictionary: (in your windowname.xaml.cs

   ```
   public Dictionary<string, List<RoutedEventHandler>> EventLibrary = new Dictionary<string, List<RoutedEventHandler>>();
   ```
4. Add an event to dictionary and extend the string with type of event

   ```
   EventLibrary.Add("NAME_RIBBONBUTTON_CLICKEVENT", new List<RoutedEventHandler> { new RoutedEventHandler(RibbonButton_Test)});
   ```
5. This is the event loaded code:

   ```
       private void RibbonButton_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonButton cmd = (System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonButton)sender;

       if (EventLibrary.ContainsKey(cmd.Tag.ToString() + "_CLICKEVENT"))
       {
           List<RoutedEventHandler> value = EventLibrary[cmd.Tag.ToString() + "_CLICKEVENT"];
           for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
           {
               cmd.AddHandler(RibbonButton.ClickEvent, value[i]);
           }
       }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link to old post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/08/04/bind-my-ribbon-ui-to-my-data-model/) in WPF blog, there you can download [archive](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/04/58/36/WpfRibbonApplication_Word.zip) with solution, where you can find couple of useful things:

- ViewModels for all Ribbon controls
- Styles with all appropriate bindings

So at the end using above things I receive more simple solution:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ribbonVM:RibbonTabVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <RibbonTab DataContext="{Binding}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ribbonVM:RibbonGroupVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
    <RibbonGroup DataContext="{Binding}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ribbonVM:RibbonButtonVM}">
    <RibbonButton DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The only thing I added to VMs were collections of child elements.